# How to print a row of a data frame with single spaces between the cells?

Tags: python

Output of the following code is:
0  A  B  C  D

```
data = pd.read_csv("file") 
print(data.loc[[0]].to_string(header=False ))
```

Which has 2 empty spaces between each variable. Why does it have 2 empty spaces? Is there a way that I can make it with one empty space between each cell(without for loop)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a fast solution but it works. Try adding: `.replace('  ',' ')` at the end of printed string.